# Anaconda navigator GUI not loading on new installation in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I just installed Anaconda3-2020.02 on my Windows 10 computer but the Anaconda navigator GUI is not running when I launched it the same problem with Spyder. The following error was reported in the command line:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy__init__.py", line 204, in from PySide import version as PYSIDE_VERSION # analysis:ignore ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils__init__.py", line 15, in from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy__init__.py", line 210, in raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found') qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found

Any ideas as to what the problem might be and how to solve it will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you run it from the command line? A quick google search for these error messages returns plenty of results, have you checked those out?

Comment: I tried running from the command line, that was when I got this error message. Nothing happens when I try to start the navigator from the GUI. I have tried some of the solutions I found on google. most have to do with installing pyside and Qt gui, but none seems to work.